# Regular Expression to extract word between the second and third space

Tags: python, regex

I am in need of some help to extract a string from the 2nd and 3rd space using pure regex and without splitting the string using library functions.

`12301: 0.355940, 0.355940 avg loss, 0.000333 rate, 11.141783 seconds, 787264 images`

I want the output to be:

`0.355940`

I have tried the following regex to extract from the second comma to the avg but failed quite badly.

`,[^avg]*`

Comment: `text.split(',')[1].strip().split(" ")[0].strip()` would still work, just in case you change your mind. As for a regex, extracting text between two strings is a long solved issue.

Comment: `re.search('([^ ]*) avg', <your_string>).groups()[0]`

Comment: @Corentin this works, why don't you post is as answer? :)

Comment: ```(\d+\.\d+)(?=\savg)```

Comment: Thank you all for your help! @scicyb 's answer was exactly what i was looking for.